# Calling Python script with arguments from VBscript

Tags: python, vbscript

I have a Python script with 2 arguments and I would like to run it via VBscript. The problem is when I type command manually in windows command line, it works without a problem. When I want to call the same script from a .vbs file, it doesn't run the .py file. A new command window appears and disappears quickly. The scripts in .vbs is :

```
SET oShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
currentCommand = "D:\xxxx\xxxxx.py aaaa bbbbbbb"
WScript.echo currentCommand
oShell.run currentCommand,1,True
```

There is no difference when add "python" to currentCommand.
I also tried like this:

```
SET oShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Dim source_code_path
source_code_path = "D:\xxxx\xxxxx.py" 
Dim variable1 
variable1 = "aaaa"
Dim variable2 
variable2 = "bbbbbbb"
Dim currentCommand 
currentCommand = source_code_path & " " & variable1 & " " & variable2 
WScript.echo currentCommand
oShell.run currentCommand,1,True
```

How can I call/run .py file with several arguments from .vbs file?

Note : When I call/run another .py without argument, it is working fine.

Comment: My commands are also working. It is partly my mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing it to:

```
currentCommand = "cmd /c " & Chr(34) & source_code_path & " " & variable1 & " " & variable2 & Chr(34)
```